# C# Entity Framework - Order by Children of Children

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-core

I am failing at using OrderBy() on the child of a child.

```
IQueryable<Conteso.Data.Models.Employee> query 
    = _context.Employee
              .Include(e => e.Person)
              .Include(e => e.Jobs).ThenInclude(j => j.EmployeeType)
              .Include(e => e.Jobs).ThenInclude(j => j.Absences).ThenInclude(a => a.AbsenceType)
              .Where(e => e.Jobs.Any(j => j.Absences.Count > 0));
```

Before sorting, there are many records in the Results View. After sorting, there are 0 items. Here is my attempt at sorting.

```
    query = query.OrderBy(e => e.Person.LastNameFirst)
                 .ThenBy(e => e.Jobs.OrderBy(j => j.Absences.OrderBy(a => a.Date)));
```

[image: SQL View]

Comment: I don't think you need the third OrderBy: (j => j.Absences.Date)

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue is that you're not selecting a key from your `ThenBy` (more info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.thenby?view=net-6.0). Consider using `.Select()` instead of your 2 `.OrderBy()`.

You could also just write:
`ThenBy(e => e.Jobs)` and make sure your Job class implements the [IEqualityComparer interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iequalitycomparer-1?view=net-6.0)

Answer (score 0):

Can't use an order by inside an order by

try

```
query = query.OrderBy(e => e.Person.LastNameFirst)
             .ThenBy(e => e.Jobs.Absences.Date);
```